# web3js getPastlog return empty array

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, geth-debugging

i test web3js by geth,i build private net in local.i try to call getPastlog ,but return empty array.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
// const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/770daaf97ee14e0aa77ac105bbcdd79f"));
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    address:"0xF81639558D54a03D6620c5bdb2f1C2e5c87736d0",
    topics: ['0xdd970dd9b5bfe707922155b058a407655cb18288b807e2216442bca8ad83d6b5'] //topics:[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint256,uint256)")]
})
.then(console.log);
```

address and topics is right ,because i get them by getPastEvents

```
contract.getPastEvents('Log', {
    // filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function (error, events) {
    console.log(events[0].raw);
});

===========result ==========
{
  data: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a54686520576f726c642100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  topics: [
    '0xdd970dd9b5bfe707922155b058a407655cb18288b807e2216442bca8ad83d6b5'
  ]
}
```

so, i want to konw why i can't get anything by pastlog.Who can help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const node_URL = 'CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL';
const web3 = new Web3(node_URL);

web3.eth.getPastLogs(
  "0xF81639558D54a03D6620c5bdb2f1C2e5c87736d0",
  ["0xdd970dd9b5bfe707922155b058a407655cb18288b807e2216442bca8ad83d6b5"],
  (err, logs) => {
    console.log(logs);
  }
);
```

And it will return this (only a short sample as it's super long):

```js
 '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017b2'
    ],
    data: '0x',
    blockNumber: 15148918,
    transactionHash: '0x1dc6e2b1b205100f355c9ed23a5692d35814953371f3117c722d2e685434a210',
    transactionIndex: 41,
    blockHash: '0x9740cc9644b12da740fb4bcee5cc7eab47a14a67cac90047bdd38f606af77791',
    logIndex: 95,
    removed: false,
    id: 'log_83c8653c'
  },
  {
    address: '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7',
    topics: [
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
      '0x000000000000000000000000b5d85cbf7cb3ee0d56b3bb207d5fc4b82f43f511',
      '0x000000000000000000000000a271fee1580d9eef821c4757fe70ec30a2c0c0f1'
    ],
    data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ea3d300',
    blockNumber: 15148918,
    transactionHash: '0x845dd44a580847c657e20d1575b4329961b1b53d03aafa6e50fa993bc51f3a2d',
    transactionIndex: 42,
    blockHash: '0x9740cc9644b12da740fb4bcee5cc7eab47a14a67cac90047bdd38f606af77791',
    logIndex: 96,
    removed: false,
    id: 'log_dcfe5163'
  },
```

You can get more details about [this RPC method](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference#eth-getlogs) in the Chainstack docs!

You can use the [Node API reference](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference) page in the [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) docs to find examples of the JSON RPC methods in web3.js, web3.py, eth.rb, and cURL!

Comment: thanks ,but it still return empty array .I can get data form test net ,such as rinkeby,but in my local geth will return empty array . I don't know if my start command lost smoething.

Comment: This is my start command: geth --http --http.corsdomain '*' --networkid 201 --mine --miner.threads 2 --syncmode full --datadir data --http  --ws --ws.port "8546" --port "30303" --http.corsdomain "*" --nat "any" --http.api eth,web3,personal,net --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0,1 --password ./password.sec

Comment: Could it be the network ID? It should be 1 for mainnet. Once you make it work, you'll need to use the syntax I sent because you will always get an empty array with the original one.

Comment: thanks,i  has resolved question. i need give blocknum as param for from and to ,so that i can get data.